# Hide Master page controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to hide master page table from the content page.

I have tried to hide the table control in different ways but I get following error message on line:

```
tbl = (HtmlTable)Page.Master.FindControl("tbl_login");
```

ERROR:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the table control on the master page and the code for hidding master page control from the login page.

[image: CODE]

There is a page called POView and it has got one link button to Approve PO and it shows POP up window which has got few controls defined one master page(text box and two button in html table) when you hit the button it sends the request to another page called Login which authenticate user password and do some updates in DB and then show the message to this POP up window (response.write).

All i want is to hide the controls (textbox and button defined on master page) from this login page.

NOTE: That Login page doesn't have any reference tag for the master page.

@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="login" %>

**ADDED:** Here is the function which is called onClick of Master page button. It is sending request to login page.

```
function showHint(str, str2, str3, reason)
{

gDiv = 'appFeedback';

xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
  return;
  }
  //replace "tricky" chars in QS
  var pwd=  str.replace('£','!!pound!!');
  pwd=  pwd.replace('£','!!pound!!');
  pwd=  pwd.replace('£','!!pound!!');
  pwd=  pwd.replace('£','!!pound!!');
  pwd=  pwd.replace('&','!!and!!');
  pwd=  pwd.replace('&','!!and!!');
  pwd=  pwd.replace('&','!!and!!');
  pwd=  pwd.replace('&','!!and!!');

var url="login.aspx";
url=url+"?q="+pwd;
url=url+"&q2="+str2;
url=url+"&q3="+str3;
url=url+"&reason="+reason;
url=url+"&entity=<%= Request["entity"] %>";
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to hide the master page controls of which page ? is it of "POView" page or ApprovePO page?

Comment: These controls are on master page and i want to hide them on the pop up window (Login page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try To call this javascript After doing the login `window.opener.document.getElementById("tbl_login").style.visibility="hidden";`

In you code it is given as

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
```

Here the "stateChanged" must be a javascript function which will be fired after doing the login.
Inside that function you can write the code to hide.

for more information about the `readystatechangedevent` please look into this :http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

**Return success from Loginpage**

```
//After doing the Logic return the status (foreg:- i return here as "success")
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write("success");
Response.End();
```

Comment: I want to hide them after updating records on the login page. Once the record has successfully been updated then hide the table.

Comment: @MOH- thanks for you comments. I have been asked to add changes (if possible) to the code written by someone else and i never used xmlHttp methods before. Whole idea is to hide buttons once the record has been updated successfully. How do i know that the reecord has been updated successfully on the login page?

Comment: Return some status from the login page when logged in , Then you can read this text from the property "xmlhttp.responseText" in side the readysateevent;

Comment: how can i return some status from the login page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14738/discussion-between-user1263981-and-moh)

Comment: i get an error saying window.opener.document is null or not an object

Comment: this problem has now been resolved. Reason i was getting that error message becuase tbl control had a runat=server value.

Answer (score 1):

When content page have directive

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Main.Master" %>
```

you have access to content of master page. Now, if you make method on master page that just hidding your table - something like this

```
public void SetTableUnvisible()
{
    tbl_login.Visible = false;
}
```

you can call this method on Page_Load event of content page

```
Master.SetTableUnvisible();
```

and your table is no more visible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to always remove the table, even though one or more pages don't even contain the table since they don't reference the master page anyway. Is that correct?

If so, your code will be falling over because you're dereferencing Page.Master anyway, even though it won't always exist. Try this, which checks to see whether there is a master page before trying to use it:

```
MasterPage master = Page.Master;
if (master != null)
{
    tbl = master.FindControl("tbl_login") as HtmlTable;
    if (tbl != null)
    {
        tbl.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it help him? login page has no master page. How could he hide the table?

Comment: If there's no master page, the if statement's condition is false so the code which hides the table never executes. This is extremely simple code.

Comment: a code that "never executes" always work. Yes, we know it, but it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I'm starting to think I'm being trolled here. Do you really not understand if statements and null checks? If there is a master page, "if (master != null)" is true so we go ahead and find/hide the table. If there isn't a master page, "if (master != null)" is false so the code inside (which finds and hides the table) is never executed.

Comment: You're not being trolled. I know your code won't fail but it won't hide the table that exists in the pop up.

Comment: I have run your code and yes it doesn't find any master page. I think there is no way to hide it.

Answer (score -2):

If your login page doesn't use the master page then you can't do it on server but with client side code only. Make a script method that hides the table. You can insert it in the master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideTable()
{
   $('#<%=tbl_login.ClientID%>').hide();
}
</script>
```

In the login page:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hide", "hideTable();", true);
```

BTW, if you want to do anything in the master page, don't try to find controls on it from your page. Write a method in the master page that do it and call it from your page. You'll need to cast `Master` to the master type, or put a master type in the master directive that do it for you.

Comment: Incorrect - there's no reason why you can't do this serverside. You just have to check that there *is* a master page before trying to call methods on the master page.

Comment: Read the question again. The page where he wants to refer the master page does not have a master page.

Comment: Read my answer again. I know the some pages don't have a master page - that's why you CHECK whether there's a master page. You only call Page.Master.FindControl(...) after checking that Page.Master != null.

Comment: @Chris i think the page (to hide the table) does not post back to server while he is doing the login, may be doing login from the popup. The question is not clear

Comment: @Chris, This page doesn't have a master page! It is written in the question! Try to offer something that works!

Comment: @Amiram I know there's no master page. That's why we check whether Page.Master exists with an if statement. If there is a master page, "if (Page.Master != null)" is true so we hide the table. If there isn't a master page, "if (Page.Master != null)" is false so we don't do anything. This is an extremely simple concept.

Comment: Ok, so `RegisterStartupScript' won't work. If you're using Response.Write then maybe you can do it with that? I didn't try it before.

Comment: XMLHttp is ajax see the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx